# How to automatically change the name of a file on a daily basis

Tags: shell-script, centos, logs, logrotate

I am new to Linux/CentOS and right now I am running into a little problem.

My CentOS7 Server logs all Maillogs on a daily basis and moves them to the folder `/var/log/old_maillogs`. Right now the logs are saved with a name similar to this:

> Maillog-20230721

I would like their names to change, based on how old they are, so that if the Log is one day old it's named:

> Maillog-1

And one the day after that, the files name changes to:

> Maillog-2

And so on.

Is this even possible, if so, what would be the smartest way to get it working?
I have read a lot about scripts that get executed once per day, but then again, how do I code the script, so that it recognizes how many logs are in the folder?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use `logrotate` which is written for exactly this purpose (it will even compress your old logs automatically). Read `man logrotate`, if something is still unclear edit your question to ask for specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by @Panki in the comments, use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

I haven't tried it, but this configuration (save it in `/etc/logrotate.d/maillog`) should do what you want:

```
/var/log/maillog {
    rotate 365
    daily
    olddir /var/log/old_maillogs
}
```